# Не работает в chrome background: -webkit-gradient,(linear-gradient)

Tags: css

```
body{
    background: -webkit-gradient(#947ad2, #00d4ff);
}
```

Comment: А где вы увидели про `gradient`? Я знаю например про `linear-gradient` и `conic-gradient`.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код для Chrome должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent 0%,#fff 50%,transparent 100%); /* Для Chrome10+ и выше */
```

Но не забывайте в конце блока написать код, стандартный для W3C:

```
background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 0%,#fff 50%,transparent 100%);      /* W3C */
```